# mongoose.connect undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, reactjs

I am trying to make a basic mongoose connection in c9.io using node.js, React, ReactRouter and webpack. I have my mongodb established and listening, but when I try to require mongoose and start a connection, it fails and tells me "undefined is not a function", pointing me to "mongoose.connect". Here is my code. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017');//this returns "undefined is not a function" and fails
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var postSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    author: String,
    content: String
});

var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

module.exports = Post;
```

Any thoughts? I am wondering if it is a problem with webpack, since I'm using React-router instead of something server-side.

Comment: did you try to print **mongoose** variable ?

Comment: Are you trying this from a web page or from Node? You won't be able to use mongoose from the client. It's only for NodeJS.

Comment: This is all from Node.

Comment: @RichardHerbert Were you able to resolve this? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Same question again, were you able to resolve this, @RichardHerbert ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are requiring this file in your client-side code (in a React component, for example), then yes, that's the problem.

You can only require this in the server-side (your "server.js" file, for example).

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. Could you explain why it can only be required on server-side? Say I didn;t care about the credentials or anything else being visible - I just want to connect and get data - is it not all possible from the React component?

Answer (score 2):

React is client side, so create an express server for mongoose, I had the same problem a few hours spent and found a good solution.

> I am trying to make a basic mongoose connection in c9.io using node.js, React, ReactRouter and webpack.
>   Okay,

MERN is fantastic.
My only problem was I couldn't use Mongoose on the React side, I came across this issue and after a few hours, I found a better solution,

No need to put anything on package.json, no need to worry about CORS,

here's a working example of a user registration using mongoose (mongoose will never run on client side, don't waste time, the library modification is time consuming),

start your express server on a port, lets say 3030, and React runs on 3000,

**on React side**,

```
constructor(){ 
...
  this.server = server || 'https://my.ip.add.ress:3030'
...
}

register(username, password, signup = true) { 
return this.fetch(`${this.server}/server/register`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username,
                password,
                signup
            })
        }).then(res => { console.log(res);
            this.setToken(res.token) // Setting the token in localStorage
            return Promise.resolve(res);
        })
}
```

**On Node.JS  server (express) side,**

Create a folder 'server' and create a file server.js,

```
var MongoNode   = require('mongoosenode')   // I created this package for just to test mongoose which doesn't run on React side, 
var cors        = require('cors');  //use cors for cross-site request

var options = {
        key     : fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
        cert    : fs.readFileSync('server.cert'),
    };

    /*
     * Cors Options
     */ 
    var whitelist = config.allowedOrigins //put https://my.ip.add.ress:3000 in the allowedOrigins array in your config file
    var corsOptions = {
        origin: function (origin, callback) {
            if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
                callback(null, true)
            } else {
                callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
            }
        }
    }
    //specify the port
    var https_port = config.server.port || 3030;

    //use app or any route included to server.js
     app.post('/register', cors(corsOptions),function(req, res) {
        //Process requests
        console.log(req.body);  //see if request payload popping up
        var mn = new MongoNode('mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/databasename')

        var user = mn.retrieveModel('User','User').then(async(res) => { 
           try { 
             user = res.model;
              console.log(user);
              user.username = req.body.username
              user.password = req.body.password
              user.token = token_str  //jwt web token to save browser cookie 
              user.save(function(err) {
                 if (err) throw err;
                 console.log('user saved successfully');
                 res.json({ success: true, token: user.token});
              });                  

           }catch(e) { 
             console.log(e);
           }
        })

        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //console.log('user saved successfully');
            res.json({ success: true , message: 'user saved successfully', token : user.token });
        });

    }
```

Voila! it's done easily after a few hours of reading.

Answer (score 0):

That error means you're calling a method that doesn't exist.
I would install mongoose module again:

`npm install mongoose --save`

Comment: 'mongoose' prints out as an object just fine, and I tried re-installing the dependency but the issue remains. It's not recognizing the method on the mongoose object for some reason. Again, this is making me believe it's an issue with webpack.

Comment: Same issue in my case as well.